# Searching major search engines with text such as <%#

Tags: php, java, .net-framework, c#, asp.net

If I type '<%# vs <%"' into any of the major search engines, everything is stripped out except the 'vs'. I understand why they do this. I would just like to know if anyone knows of a way to escape illegal characters so that they are searched properly.

I know this is not strictly a programming question, but it is relevant.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132105/how-to-google-for-depend/132152#132152

Comment: It is all very well voting to close this, but when I searched SO for <%# it stripped out those characters as well, so how was I supposed to find the existing question?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Code Search is discontinued, how about [Search Code](http://searchco.de/)?